# What's the meaning of "made up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This is a passage from a novel:

> He smiled as he **made up** her plate. Stir-fry. Salmon. Kale. Other green things. He crushed a handful of cashews in his fist and sprinkled them on top, then set the plate in front of her.

*her* is the wife.

What does "made up" mean in the passage?

Edit:

I looked up [*make up*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make-up_2) on OALD, and my guess is that number 2 of the definitions fits most appropriately to the context?

> 2. to put something together from several different things

Comment: You might get some downvotes or close votes because you've not indicated any effort to look this up (or, if you did, you haven't shown what you found). I recommend doing some dictionary work first, before you ask on ELL. If you have done that already, then you should edit the question, and add a sentence or two explaining why your search proved fruitless. The community will appreciate that information. It wouldn't hurt to specify [what novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ) this came from, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial intuition is correct. The meaning of *made up* can be intuited from the context. More specifically, it simply seems to have the meaning of *make*, just as some people say *clean* while others say *clean up*.

It is a bit old-fashioned, so far as I can tell. Here is an instance from a 19th-century trial :

*It has been stated by your lordship, that the first question at the trial was, whether it was the duty of the accountant at the payoffice, to make up the ex-paymaster's accounts.*

Note that the usage here is pretty similar: the phrase implies that the accounts are being created, not falsified. Interestingly, your example comes from a work published quite recently. I suppose it might still be used more frequently in certain styles of English.